# Java JSON Deserialization Error

Tags: java, json, deserialization

I have the following code that uses [Java JSON](http://json.org/java/):

```
Widget w = new Widget(true, "LIVE");
WidgetService service = new WidgetServiceImpl();    // 3rd party JSON web service

JSONObject response = service.postWidget(w);

System.out.println("Response is: " + response.toString());
System.out.println("Now fetching orderid...");
System.out.println(response.getString("order_id"));
```

Don't worry about `Widget` or `WidgetService`: this question has to do with how I'm using the Java JSON API (and specifically `JSONObject`).

When I run the above code, I get:

```
Response is: {"response":{"credits_used":"0.30","job_count":1,"order_id":"243050","currency":"USD"},"opstat":"ok"}
Now fetching orderid...
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["order_id"] not found.
    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:473)
    at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:654)
    at com.me.myapp.MyDriver.main(MyDriver.java:49)
```

As you can see, there is an order_id String field coming back in the response, and it has a value of "243050". So why am I getting the exception?

Comment: the orderid is not directly linked to the response object, it is within another object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `JSONObject response` points to the outer json object.

I am pretty sure, your response object has a property `"response"` (and `"opstat"` btw.) containing your expected object.

Comment: Thanks @Max Fichtelmann (+1) - so what do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: [JSONObject#getJSONObject(String)](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONObject(java.lang.String)) should get the inner response Object, just like @dstronczak said.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it like this:

```
response.getJSONObject("response").getString("order_id");
```